# C# Lambda Aggregate method - how to remove extra word

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, lambda

Hi I am using Aggregate method to create a string of words, in the word I want to remove the last word which got added.

For example :

```
private string BuildContainPartialSearch ( string cleanedSearchTerm  )
{ 
    string newSearchTerm = string.Empty ;
    return cleanedSearchTerm.Any ( char.IsWhiteSpace )? ( 
    cleanedSearchTerm.Split ( ' ' ).Aggregate ( newSearchTerm ,( current , 
    term 
    ) => current + $" /.*{term}.*/ OR" ) ): $"/.*{cleanedSearchTerm}.*/" ;
}
```

If i pass parameter `< One two >` with spaces between the output will be `/.* One. * / OR /.* two. */ OR` but I want the last `OR` should not be added.

Please advise how can I use aggregate in such a way that it does not add the last "OR" in the return string.

Comment: Have you considered [`string.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: `string.Join(" OR ", (new[] { "one", "two" }).Select(x => $"/.*{x}.*/"))`

Comment: But i want to use aggregate as the parameter can have n-Number of words or single word

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if aggregate can do this.
What about simple string (post) operations, since the last word will be preceeded by a whitespace:

```
string s = "sdfsadf asdf dsa fds";
int i = s.LastIndexOf(' ');
if (i > 0)
{
   var result = s.Substring(0, i);
   //... 
   //res.Dump(); // Linqpad
}
```

Comment: Aggregate should be able to do as its creating the content and its returning the parsed new string. So after aggregating it should be possible to remove the unwanted character from the string of words.